# Postgresql search using only alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's pretty straightforward to strip out non-alphanumeric characters out from the search term, but how do you compare it to only the non-alphanumeric characters of values in the database?

For example, if I search for `stack's`, how can I get it to match both `stacks` and `stack's`?

What do I need to do to the `what-do-i-do` variable below to make the above happen?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <what-do-i-do> ilike 'stacks'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is with translate:

```
select *
from table
where translate(lower(WhatIDo), translate(lower(WhatIDo), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''), '') = 'stacks'
```

The inner translate finds all non-alpha characters.  The outer then removes these from the string.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! While i was waiting I also got it to work using regex_replace: `regexp_replace(whatdoido, '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '') ilike 'stacks'`

Comment: @spyd3rr . . . Very good solution.  I figured there was a way with regular expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace all instances of non-alphanumeric characters with the wildcard character ('%'). In your example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data like 'stack%s'
```